# internet available or not in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

how to check whether internet is available or not in codenameone?

I have used [`getAutoDetectUrl`](https://codenameone.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/CodenameOne/javadoc/com/codename1/io/NetworkManager.html#getAutoDetectURL%28%29) method of Networkmanager.

And this method always return the following text:

```
http://www.google.com/
```

And it throws following exception in case of network disconnected

```
java.io.IOException: Unreachable
```

So how can I check whether internet is available or not?

Comment: add a `try { } catch` block?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it this way:

```
public static boolean am_i_online() {
    boolean online = false;
    String net = NetworkManager.getInstance().getCurrentAccessPoint();
    if (net == null || net == "" || net.equals(null)) {
        online = false;
    } else {
        online = true;
    }
        return online;
}
```

Although, this checks only if your device is connected with a WLAN hotspot or a mobile network and not if you are able to connect to a remote webserver.

Nevertheless I decided for this approach rather than trying to connect to a remote host with `ConnectionRequest` mainly because of simplicity, speed and the fact thats not necessary to "call home" all the time.

Currently it seems that this solution works for WLAN as well as mobile data connections.

Comment: Another approach would be using the CN1LIBS plugin [connectivity](https://github.com/littlemonkeyltd/codenameone-connectivity). Although it calls home on every usage, it probes for a real internet connection and is able to tell you the used connection type (WIFI or mobile data).

Comment: can you elabrate in detail ?how to use CN1LIBS plugin connectivity to check internet connection(its good if you mention some sample code for it)

Comment: @ShekharJadhav basiclly by using this example:
`if (Connectivity.isConnected()) {
    //we have some connection
} else {
    // we have no connection
}` it's from the [README](https://github.com/littlemonkeyltd/codenameone-connectivity) of the GitHub project site. If your question is how to use the CN1LIBS check out [this](https://www.codenameone.com/cn1libs.html)

Answer (score 0):

The auto detect URL is used internally in Codename One. The getter is exposed for consistency.

To see if a site is available just try to connect to it using the `ConnectionRequest` class. You can invoke `setFailSilently(true)` so it will not throw an exception and test the response code to see that you got a 200 response code.